# Lists evaluates to boolean but return as a list

Tags: python

I'm new to python (3.6) and I wrote:

```
def foo(alist, blist):
    if alist or blist:
        return alist or blist

print(foo([2], []))
```

which prints `[2]`.

And I'm trying to understand: it seems like that a list is evaluate to `False` \ `True` in the `if alist or blist` but in the `return alist or blist` it returns the list itself and not a `False` \ `True`. How's that?

Does `alist or blist` evaluates to the non-empty list of the two? Are there any rules written somewhere in the docs for all that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first list `[2]` could be considered a `True` value in opposition to the  second empty list `[]` which is [`False`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in a *boolean* context.

> The following values are considered **false**:
>   ....
>
> **any empty sequence**, for example, '', (), **[]**.

---

> `x or y`  if x is false, then y, **else x**
>
> This is a short-circuit operator, so **it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false**

Check the [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

---

From the *interpreter*:

```
>>> ['test'] or []
['test']
>>>
>>> ['test'] or ['test2']
['test']
>>>
>>> [] or ['test2']
['test2']
>>>
>>> [] or []
[]
```

Comment: and in `return alist or blist`? it's evaluates to the non-empty one?

Comment: isn't it more that a _non-empty_ list is truthy? For example, if you called `foo([2], [4])` there's no "empty list behaviour" - `[2]` is returned because of its truthiness

Comment: `if x is false, then y, else x` , that's the reason of `[2]` return -> `else x`. And of course a non empty list is *True*  @asongtoruin

Comment: @klashxx yes I know - but your answer is just worded in a way that suggests the critical part of the example given is the falsiness of the empty list when it isn't - it's the truthiness of a non-empty list that results in `[2]` being returned in the example provided.

Comment: While this line is directly from the docs, I think saying that `x or y` behaves as `x if bool(x) else y` is a bit clearer. (And, yes, I know the `bool` is redundant.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the code commenting to understand the code:

```
def foo(alist, blist):
    if alist or blist:

        #this if condition checks if alist is empty or blist is empty
        # Means: in actual this condition will be like this
        if alist != None or blist != None
        #None means if the list is empty or not

       return alist or blist

       # it returns the non-empty list just like the above explanation 
       # If both lists have some values then it will always return the first list which is alist

print(foo([2], []))
# Try you code with following statements to understand it

print(foo([], []))
# You will get None

print(foo([2], [3]))
# You will get [2]

print(foo([2], [2,4,5]))
# You will get [2]

print(foo([], [3]))
# You will get [3]
```